# AttributeError Django 2.2.5

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I am getting AttributeError :
QuerySet object has no attribute 'name'.
Not able to retrieve data from objects.
I am using default database configuration for sqlite3

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Sorry! No need I have resolved the error.

Comment: If so, you may [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question.